# Defining custom lifecycle phases in Maven 2

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

In my `pom.xml` I have referenced a custom plugin, which is exposing a couple of goals. While I can attach these goals to the various build life-cycle phases, I would like to be able to invoke a set of goals defined in the POM by using my custom alias *phase* on the command line, such as:

```
mvn myphase
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? I would like to avoid modifying my plugin as I need to run some auxiliary operations, which are provided by the antrun plugin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to invoke a custom **phase** not a **goal** (changed your question). You have to write your custom lifecycle which will include your custom phase. Do you really want to do that? Have a look at [this](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingACustomLifecycleInMaven).